# using Moq - void return type method Unit test

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, moq

I am writing unittest for void method actually that method load the collection in 
ViewData["CityList"] method is

```
 public void PopulateCityCombo() {
            IEnumerable<Cities> c= service.GetCities();
           ViewData["CityList"] = c.Select(e => new Cities{ ID = e.ID, Name = e.Name});
        }
```

now i do not know how to unit test using Moq since controller method is void and not returning data, can any one tell i will achive that.

Comment: Can you not validate the ViewData entries in your test. Just invoke the "PopulateCityCombo" method and then validate the content of ViewData collection in your test.

Answer (score 3):

On a side note, I would shy away from using ViewData within controller methods as per your example. The ViewData dictionary approach is fast and fairly easy to implement, however it can lead to typo's and errors that are not caught at compile time. An alternative would be to use the ViewModel pattern which allows you to use strongly-typed classes for the specific view you need to expose values or content within. Ultimately giving you type safe and compile time checking along with intellisense.

Switching to the ViewModel pattern would allow you to call the PopulateCityCombo() method from your controller to populate a ViewModel that in turn would passed to the corresponding view.

From there you would need to inject a mock service layer into your controllers constructor from your unit test.

```
// arrange
var mock = new Mock<servicelayer>();
mock.Setup(x=>x.GetCities()).Returns(expectedData);

var controller = new YourController(mock.Object);

// act
var result = controller.ControllerMethod() as ViewResult;
var resultData = (YourViewModel)result.ViewData.Model;

// assert
// Your assertions
```

Comment: You gave me very good suggestion, but because of time constriant i do not want to change my implementation.I am using that because this is recomended way to populate editor template by telerik since this is my first project in MVC and first time i am using Moq i did not had idea i can use view model for that. Please tell me with exisiting code.

Comment: I am waiting for your comment

Comment: If you do not have time to transition to use a viewmodel, the testing process would be much the same. Inject a mocked service layer into your controller, call the related view method and verify the viewdata